# Setting up Web.MVC & Host sites on different servers

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, n-tier-architecture

I'm new to ABP Core framework. I'm working with the sample project available at https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Core

I have deployed host API in separate server. Any help in how to access API from Web.MVC project from different server? I would like to eliminate DB calls from presentation layer. when I try to debug MVC site locally, I am seeing ABP is initiating SQL connection. any sample to demonstrate multiple server deployment will be helpful.

I tried to host sites in different servers. I'm looking for configuration in MVC site where exactly I should add API URL.

Comment: The MVC template provided by abp is not design to be database agnostic. Currently the db agnostic templates are only available in angular/react/vue

Comment: thanks @ryan.c is there anyway we can get help from ABP team by buying the paid version. I need a MVC sample to deploy API into internal server and UI into external server.